# What kind of resources does a process or a thread require in JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading

I came across the Java documentations that said

> Both processes and threads provide an execution environment, but
>   creating a new thread requires fewer resources than creating a new
>   process.

Ref:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html

In this context what actually do we mean by resources?

**EDIT1:**

Also why is `Runnable` faster than `Threads`?

What are the generic resources?

What is the difference in resources both are using?

Comment: There are about five separate questions here. `Runnables` are not faster than `Threads`. 'Generic resources' doesn't mean anything in particular.  The final question is meaningless until you specify what 'both' refers to. Too broad.

Comment: @EJP My question was focused on the resources each of them uses and not about the speed. I know there are questions related to `why runnable are faster than threads` but no  questions i found which spoke about what resources where required.

Comment: Your question asks, and I quote, 'why is `Runnable` faster than `Threads`?', and the answer is that it isn't.

Comment: in terms of initialisation. As runnable requires lesser resources than Threads they are faster. As a whole they are just functions and their execution depends on the underlying logic. Am I right ? Correct me if I'm not

Comment: They are *not* faster. They are faster *if you don't execute them as threads*, which eliminates the whole point of having them at all. Any *method call* is faster than starting a thread to execute it, but there is no parallelism, which may in reality make the whole computation slower. Your statement has no essential meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spawning a new process will create a new Java Virtual Machine.

Where as threads will share memory, JVM's, etc.

The JVM is not a light program, so will consume more memory, etc.

Some JVM's are multi-process, allowing multiple processes to share a JVM.

From the linked tutorial in the question:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html

> A process generally has a complete, private set of basic run-time
>   resources; in particular, each process has its own memory space.

and

> Threads share the process's resources, including memory and open files. This makes for efficient, but potentially problematic, communication.

---

To address EDIT 1.

First lets define some general computing terms.

**Operating System Concepts**

**Resources**
From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_resource

> In computing, a system resource, or simply resource, is any physical
>   or virtual component of limited availability within a computer system.
>   Every device connected to a computer system is a resource. Every
>   internal system component is a resource. Virtual system resources
>   include files (concretely file handles), network connections
>   (concretely network sockets), and memory areas

**Process**
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)

> In computing, a process is an instance of a computer program that is being executed. It contains the program code and its current activity. Depending on the operating system (OS), a process may be made up of multiple threads of execution that execute instructions concurrently.

**Thread**
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)

> In computer science, a thread of execution is the smallest sequence of programmed instructions that can be managed independently by a scheduler, which is typically a part of the operating system.

**Java Concepts**

**Process**

In relation to Java, a Process typically runs a separate JVM, different heaps, etc.

**Threads**

Threads share a JVM, and are able to access the same classes and memory, but since they are a concept outside of Java, relating to the Operating System, there are overheads for interacting / creating them.

**Runnable** - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html

A Runnable is a concept included only within Java that the OS is not aware of, it's literally just an interface with a method called run, however you need to handle running it yourself.

The reason for abstracting it away from threads, is that the classes involving threads themselves have to concern themselves with compatibility with the underlying operating system bindings, your runnable doesn't need to know any of this, it's just code that's expected to run in a Java context.

It's really just a marker to show others that you plan for this to be run by a thread, or some other form of scheduled execution.

Where as Threads are external concepts, managed by the operating system, thus have costs relating to memory, context switching, etc.

Processes are even more costly, and have separate program memory that is not shared.

Comment: yes, I get you but my question is very specific. What are the resources that is use. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_(Java)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_(Java)) is this what a thread uses.

Comment: That's not what it's referring to. The use of the word Resource here is the generic version of it, not the specific Uniform Resource Location kind.

Comment: check out EDIT1

Comment: So is it like a `Runnable` resources are the members of the implementing class where as the `Thread` resources are in terms of the CPU or the machine that is being used and is mapped by the operating system rather than the program itself

Answer (score 1):

Everything related with the environment, like cpu,memory, disk, network, etc.